# ORACLE SQL Developer Dark Mode

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle10g

Is there any official method to use ORACLE Dark Mode?

Comment: One option, have it adopt your OS theme for look and feel https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2017/08/look-and-feel-feel-free-to-go-crazy/

Comment: Or use a dark theme for code editors a la https://draculatheme.com/oracle-sql-developer

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Tools > Preferences > Code Editor > PL/SQL Syntax Colors.
Here you can choose Twilight scheme.

Comment: but this just changes the code editor, leaving the rest bright... it doesn't look good

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no official method. There is a way to change it manually through, through editing a jar file. [Here is the full video if it helps you out.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=znGzJOgQmHk) By default you can only change the Syntax colors + background of the editor.

Answer (score 4):

## Try to do this

### OS: Debian Linux

Desktop: Gnome 40
JDK: Open JDK 11

edit ~/.sqldeveloper/{version}/product.conf

add (the system theme will be used):

SetJavaHome /{path to open11jdk}
AddVMOption -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel

If you would like to use a different theme that is not set for the system:
edit ~/.sqldeveloper/{version}/product.conf
add (after the above changes):
GTK_THEME={theme name}

export GTK_THEME

### Windows 10:

edit: {user}/AppData/Roaming/sqldeveloper/{version}/product.conf

add:

AddVMOption -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel

Sqldeveloper will use the current default Windows 10 theme

Answer (score 1):

See this:  [here](https://draculatheme.com/oracle-sql-developer). Also in the site you can find dark themes for other tools and software.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35370373)